# Not getting the desired output in logstash

Tags: logstash

I am not able to get any output on the command prompt screen

```
E:\kibana\logstash-7.1.1\logstash-7.1.1>bin\logstash -f E:\kibana\logstash-7.1.1\logstash-7.1.1\config\pipeline.conf --config.reload.automatic

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.runtime.encoding.EncodingService (file:/E:/kibana/logstash-7.1.1/logstash-7.1.1/logstash-core/lib/jars/jruby-complete-9.2.7.0.jar) to field java.io.Console.cs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.runtime.encoding.EncodingService
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Sending Logstash logs to E:/kibana/logstash-7.1.1/logstash-7.1.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-06-14T12:33:19,407][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-06-14T12:33:19,427][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.1.1"}
[2019-06-14T12:33:22,210][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x6177c4b4 run>"}
[2019-06-14T12:33:23,035][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"E:/kibana/logstash-7.1.1/logstash-7.1.1/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_039f8a57349afd1e3fb106bf0e1c330b", :path=>["/E/kibana/logstash-7.1.1/logstash-7.1.1/data/event-data/apache_access.log"]}
[2019-06-14T12:33:23,119][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2019-06-14T12:33:23,189][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2019-06-14T12:33:23,198][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2019-06-14T12:33:23,479][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

I am only getting this and not the output.  What could be going wrong?

Comment: What is the desired output? What is your source message and what you expect to see? What is your pipeline configuration? You need to share more information about what you are doing.

Comment: input 
{
    file {
    
     path=>"/E/kibana/logstash-7.1.1/logstash-7.1.1/data/event-data/apache_access.logs"
        type => "apache-access" 
     start_position => "beginning"
      
         
         }               
 
}                                         
 
output
{
   stdout{
       
          codec=>rubydebug  
       
         }
 
 
}(this is my configuration file)

Comment: Your path is wrong, try changing it to `path => "E:/kibana/logstash-7.1.1/logstash-7.1.1/data/event-data/apache_access.logs" `

Comment: I tried doing what you are saying(Your path is wrong, try changing it to path => "E:/kibana/logstash-7.1.1/logstash-7.1.1/data/event-data/apache_access.logs" – leandrojmp ) but there is no change ,i am getting the same problem again and again (help me

Comment: You need to provide more information, update your question with your message and what you expect the output to be.